# How to make sql foreach loop by Laravel Query builder?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, postgresql, foreach

I have an array. Can I send the values ​​in an array with one query and get a separate response for all arrays ...?

```
$regions:  array;
```

> $result is laravel query result
>
> ['index'] is index from SQL

```
$data['persons'] = $reslut['index']['persons'];
$data['companies'] = $reslut['index']['companies'];
```

**If I am sending an array to sql and can it return a separate value for each value? That is, the foreach loop should use sql and return the results to individual variables. Can I write in any of the indexes?**

Comment: What `$regions`, `$reslut`? Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

Comment: if I am sending an array to sql and can it return a separate value for each value? That is, the foreach loop should use sql and return the results to individual variables. Can I write in any of the indexes?

Comment: Please review [ask]. Following that as a template for your question greatly enhances your chance of getting a satisfactory answer. In this particular case provide sample date - as text NO images - and the expected output from that data. Also what have you tried and what is incorrect with them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query array data with a whereIn statement:

`$results = Model::whereIn('your_field', $array)->get()`

This will respond with a collection that contains multiple results. You can loop over them with `for($results as $result){}` or count them with `$results->count()`

.. But i'm not complete sure I did understand your question correct ;)